# lumen-logging with dynamic path at run time

Tags: laravel, logging, lumen, monolog

I have used this function in `bootstrap/app.php` file

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) {
 $maxFiles = 7;

 $rotatingLogHandler = (new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path('logs/lumen.log'), $maxFiles))
    ->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));

 $monolog->setHandlers([$rotatingLogHandler]);

 return $monolog;
 });
```

It is working to generate log file based on date. But I want to generate log file user wise for that every time I have to change log file path like,

```
storeage/logs/USERID/DATEWISELOG.log
```

Instead of create logfile as `storeage/logs/DATEWISELOG.log`

Is it possible to generate `logfile` path based on user?

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont always have an authenticated user, it would be technically difficult.

Then the log handler is bootstrapped before most of the providers including database one, so it would be very difficult to make it dependent on logged in user.

Unless you hack in something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my answer

in **bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) {
 $maxFiles = 7;

 $rotatingLogHandler = (new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(config("path"), $maxFiles))
    ->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));

 $monolog->setHandlers([$rotatingLogHandler]);

 return $monolog;
 });
```

when user logged in then change the value of config("path") as below,

```
config(['path' => storage_path('logs')."/".$user->user_id."/lumen.log"]);
```

it will change the value of config at run time.